# How to setup a cron job for a list of pending jobs in my database

Tags: php, email, cron, alert

I have a built a project management system for my company, and so this project system holds a list of jobs the company does using my sql database.

And so to make this application work more effectively, I would like to setup a notification system that sends an email to an admin letting him/her know that there pending jobs.

This notifications would be sent daily. I have done a research on this and found out that setting up a cron job would fit this purpose.
I have search online on how to setup a cron job, but the links I see are not related to the kinda things I want to do.

So I am asking how I can setup a cron job, so that email alerts would be sent to an admin email wen they are pending jobs.

My language for this application is php and mysql

Comment: What do you mean by "The links I see are not related to the kinda things"? Do you want to set a cron job by editing crontab, or programmatically by a certain API? Are you even working on a -ix system, or do you search a solution for Windows? The answers will help the community to help you.

Comment: ok first of all i dont knw too much about settting up a cron job, so wat i am trying to do is to send email notifications daily from my web application built with php and my sql. my intention is to set a reminder that there are jobs in my database that are still pending, is what i have said clear enough, you can advice me on what to best to try for my question iv asked

Comment: Go to Google and enter "tutorial setting cron job". Let yourself help by people that have written good tutorials that give advice. E.g. [http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) But just to remember: I asked what operating system you are working on. If you are not working on Linux or Unix, there will be no cron jobs at all, they are a Linux/Unix feature. Try to narrow down what you really have and really need.

Comment: oh about that, i am working on a linux based server, thank u very much